# Can I use existing Visual Studio 2017 Workloads (from Community Edition) on a Visual Studio 2017 Professional Edition?

Tags: visual-studio

I've upgraded to Visual Studio 2017 Professional - to replace my existing Community Edition installation. I'm currently on the go, and have only limited data via my phone.

I was wondering if there is a way to migrate my existing workloads (ie VSTO, .NET Desktop Development, Universal Windows Platform Development, ASP.NET and Web Development, etc... that you select at installation) from my 2017 Community Edition installation, or if they are incompatible and I will have to download everything once again.

My existing Community Edition Installation is V15.0.
My new Professional Installation is V15.7.1.

I know it is easy to bring up the installer to get these packages when I once again have real internet access, but in my current situation, I won't have that real internet access for a while and need to utilise those development workloads in the meantime - is there a way to migrate these packages?

Thanks.

Comment: This question won't really help others. The installation bits of Community and Professional editions of course have overlapped packages, which if you hack enough, can save some download bits. But who would waste so much time when finding a free WIFI would be much easier a way to go.

Answer (score 0):

there is a way but I can't guarantee for you the stability of the new installation.

copy the content of folder `yourDisk:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community` to

```
yourDisk:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional
```

Be careful when copying dlls do not merge some existing files if they match in name and don't match in version or in size (you should compare dll with binary comparaison.